# Multithreading in C, Fibonacci Program

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have newly started studying operating systems and creating processes/threads on Linux system by using C programming language(thats what is expected us to use) but I have some problems on the code that I've been trying to write:

Here is my code written on an Ubuntu system:

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int total = 0;

   typedef struct
   {
    int start;
    int end;
    int threadNo;
   }THREAD_PARAMETERS;

  void *work(void *parameters);
  int threadCount;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {

      printf("please give the number of terms you want to diplay..");
      scanf("%d", &threadCount);

     pthread_t tid[threadCount];
     pthread_attr_t attr[threadCount];

     THREAD_PARAMETERS* lpParameter;

      int n;

    lpParameter = malloc(sizeof(THREAD_PARAMETERS)* threadCount);

    int  i=0;

    for(i=0; i<threadCount; i++)
    {
     lpParameter[i].start = 0;
     lpParameter[i].end = 1;
     lpParameter[i].threadNo = i + 1;

     pthread_attr_init(&attr[i]);
     pthread_create(&tid[i],&attr[i],work,&lpParameter[i]); 
    }

    for(i=0; i<threadCount; i++)
    {
    pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }
    return 1;
    }



    void fibonacci(int a)
    {
     int  prev_term = 0, current_term = 1, next_term = 0;

     if(a==0){
     printf("%d\n",prev_term);

     }
     else if(a==1){

     next_term=current_term+prev_term;
     printf("%d\n",current_term);
     prev_term=current_term;
     current_term=next_term;

    void *work(void * parameters)
    {
    THREAD_PARAMETERS* param = (THREAD_PARAMETERS*)parameters;
    fibonacci(threadCount);
    pthread_exit(0);
    }
```

The problem is the program counts with the threadCount variable but what the program prints is just threadCount times zeros.
And the main question is how can I make each of the threads write "only one term" of the Fibonacci series depending on the number of terms (which is at the same time the number of threads) entered by the user? Is there any other more logical way to implement this kind of program?

Comment: What does "threadCount times zeros" mean?

Comment: Note that there is a closed form solution to the Fibonacci series, so loops, much less threads, are not needed.

Comment: if threadCount is 3 it prints zero three times for example.

Comment: But if you *do* implement a thread-based Fibonacci calculator in any but the most trivial of ways, then you gain very little, if anything, from the threading, because you'll need to serialize the threads' operations.

Comment: Your thread function, `work()`, does exactly the same thing in every thread, regardless of the parameters you provide to each one.

Comment: There is no divide and conquer advantage to be gained in the Fibonacci calculation. The best you can do is launch a thread to pre-calculate all the answers and place them in a table, while another thread actually handles queries and does a table lookup or wait for the calculating thread to put in an answer.

Comment: The code presented is invalid -- function `fibonacci()` seems to be truncated.

Comment: Actually what I am expected to do is to make each of the threads write one term of the Fibonacci series.You may be right about its being inefficient or harder with this kind of thread usage.But the task I have do do is as I explained here.

Comment: this seems to be one of those "you are forced to implement in this way" scenarios where the  person/teacher asking for this could not find a better and more real usage than the Fibonacci series

Answer (score 0):

You are using `lpParameter[i]` as the argument to each thread's `work`, but then ignore its contents when calling `fibonacci`.